# How to access unconverted driver.Value slice of sql.Rows

Tags: go

My goal is to get to the raw `driver.Value` values as deserialized by a sql driver in its implementation of `driver.Rows.Next()`. **I want to handle the conversion from the values returned by the driver to the needed target types,  instead of relying on the automatic conversions built in to `Rows.Scan`.** Note this question does not ask your opinion on whether `Rows.Scan` "should" be used. I don't want to use it, and I am asking if there is any way to avoid it.

**A meaningful answer does not use `Rows.Scan` at all**. The dynamic approach illustrated in [Working with Unknown Columns](http://go-database-sql.org/varcols.html) is awful: It invokes all the overhead of Scan *and destroys the type information of the source columns*, instead shredding the actual `driver.Value`s into `SqlBytes`.

The following hack works, but relies on the internal implementation detail that `sql.Rows.Next()` populates the internal field `lastcols` with exactly the unconverted values which I want:

```golang
vpRows := reflect.ValueOf(rows)                    // rows is a *sql.Rows
vRows := reflect.Indirect(vpRows)                  // now we have the sql.Rows struct
mem := vRows.FieldByName("lastcols")               // unexported field lastcols
unsafeLastCols := unsafe.Pointer(mem.UnsafeAddr()) // Evil
plastCols := (*[]driver.Value)(unsafeLastCols)     // But effective

for rows.Next() {
    rowVals := *plastCols
    fmt.Println(rowVals)
}
```

Comment: The only way to accomplish this is to write your own driver implementation that wraps your underlying driver.

Comment: That said, this does sound entirely like an XY Problem, which you seem to know :)

Comment: Apart from implementing the Scanner interface *and* using that in Scan, I don't think there's anything else in `database/sql` that would give you the driver.Value that's fed to `*sql.Rows`... Depending on what database you're talking to, you may want to look at lower-level implementations of the driver, such as [pgx](https://github.com/jackc/pgx) for example.

Comment: @Flimzy I disagree on that. It's entirely reasonable to decouple the mechanics of retrieving values from a database from the business logic of conversions to the runtime representations.

Comment: What are you disagreeing with?

Comment: "It's entirely reasonable to decouple the mechanics of retrieving values from a database from the business logic of conversions to the runtime representations." -- I agree with this completely. As do the authors of the sql driver, which is why it's possible to implement your own Scanner, to do just that.

Answer (score 1):

The normal solution is to implement your own [`sql.Scanner`](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Scanner).  But this does use `rows.Scan`, so it violates your mysterious requirement not to use `rows.Scan`.

If you truly must avoid `rows.Scan`, you'll need to write your own driver implementation (possibly wrapping an existing driver) which provides access to the `driver.Value` values without `rows.Scan`.